# Set up Postgres

Tags: postgresql, database, helpfile

I recently istalled PostgresSQL , but when I enter `psql` to the terminal, if gives me the error:

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

This is the socket I want to use.  How do I set up PostgresSQL ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645550/postgresql-why-psql-cant-connect-to-server

Comment: I'm not sure I follow

Comment: ```sudo find /tmp/ -name .s.PGSQL.5432
find: ‘/tmp/.mount_pcloudwWkTBf’: Permission denied```

Comment: How did you install PostgreSQL? Have you confirmed that the service is running?

Comment: The service does not appear to be running

Comment: postgres' website provides this

Comment: ```sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql```

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

Comment: What Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: Have you try reinstall? I can run it successfully..

Comment: I purged and installed, now when I try to set up a database I get this ```no driver was registered for the schema "", did you maybe forget to require the database driver?```